# improve a code to find followers of followers with twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

I need help on this one:

I have created this code in python but I don't find a way to improve it and make it shorter as there is some steps that are repeated. This is what I got so far. What I am trying to do is to get first the followers of the early adopter list, then get the followers of the followers, and do the same step three more times.

```
early_adopters = ['user_ID_1', 'user_ID_2']

users_follower = [] # list of every followers from early adopters 
follower_list = [] # list of pairs of users (early_apdoter, follower)

for usr in early_adopters:
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr).items(3):
    if user.id not in early_adopters:
      users_follower.append(user.id_str)
      follower_list.append((usr,user.id_str))


users_follower_S1 = random.choices(users_follower, k=3) # sample of user from the first surface follower_list_search
follower_list_1 = []  #list of pair of followers of followers 
s2_follower_list = [] # list of pairs of users (early_apdoter, follower) 

for usr_s1 in users_follower_S1:
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr_s1).items(3):
    if user.id_str not in follower_list and usr_s1 not in early_adopters:
      follower_list_1.append(user.id_str)
      s2_follower_list.append((usr_s1, user.id_str))


users_follower_S2 = random.choices(follower_list_1, k=3) # Repeat the same process above but for the second surface 
follower_list_2 = []
s3_follower_list = [] 

for usr_s2 in users_follower_S2:
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr_s2).items(3):
    if user.id_str not in follower_list and usr_s2 not in early_adopters:
      follower_list_2.append(user.id_str)
      s3_follower_list.append((usr_s2, user.id_str))


users_follower_S3 = random.choices(follower_list_2, k=3) # Repeat the same process above but for the second surface 
follower_list_3 = []
s4_follower_list = [] 

for usr_s3 in users_follower_S3:
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr_s3).items(3):
    if user.id_str not in follower_list and usr_s3 not in early_adopters:
      follower_list_3.append(user.id_str)
      s4_follower_list.append((usr_s3, user.id_str))
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Probably wrap the repeated code in a function, e.g.:

```
def getFollowers(users)
    followers = []
    follower_pairs = []

    for usr in users:
      for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr).items(3):
        if user.id not in users and user.id not in early_adopters:
          followers.append(user.id_str)
          follower_pairs.append((usr,user.id_str))

    return (followers, follower_pairs)
```

Example use case:

```
early_adopters = ['user_ID_1', 'user_ID_2']

users_follower, follower_list = getFollowers(early_adopters)
```

I might be missing something from your logic, but this is my overall suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think here we are just getting the followers of the list but we are still missing the follower of the followers

Comment: @sarandonga2912 For a 'second round', I believe you can call `users_follower2, follower_list2 = getFollowers(users_follower)`, where the argument `users_follower` is the result of the 'first round'. Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah make sense. Thanks!